# Keep one column data and fill other columns with 0s in matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a 47x47 matrix that I want to parse and create 47 similar matrices that each contain solely one of the columns and other columns would be 0.

```
From the matrix:
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  1.00 -0.25   0.2
[2,] -0.25  1.00   0.3
[3,]   1      2     3

I would like to obtain 3 matrices

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  1.00     0    0
[2,] -0.25     0    0
[3,]   1       0    0

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]   0  -0.25    0
[2,]   0   1.00    0
[3,]   0    2      0

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]   0     0    0.2
[2,]   0     0    0.3
[3,]   0     0     3
```

I suspect this can be achieved with a nested loop.

Comment: If `x` is your matrix, try `lapply(seq_len(ncol(x)),function(y) {x[,-y]<-0;x})`.

Comment: @nicola Thanks nicola, your solution creates a list that assigns the first column to 0s and keeps all the other data, then assigns the second column and keeps the rest of the data. What I want is the opposite, only keep column one and then all other columns 0, Then keep second column and all other columns 0, etc etc Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems to me that my line (did you try running it and inspecting the result?) does what you are asking. It keeps just one column and set any other to 0. Try it for a 5x5 matrix: `x<-matrix(runif(25),ncol=5)` and then run my line.

Comment: @nicola yes, sorry you are completely right Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `bdiag` to create a single matrix instead of a `list`

```
library(Matrix)
as.matrix(bdiag(split(m1, col(m1))))
#       [,1]  [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  1.00  0.00  0.0
# [2,] -0.25  0.00  0.0
# [3,]  1.00  0.00  0.0
# [4,]  0.00 -0.25  0.0
# [5,]  0.00  1.00  0.0
# [6,]  0.00  2.00  0.0
# [7,]  0.00  0.00  0.2
# [8,]  0.00  0.00  0.3
# [9,]  0.00  0.00  3.0
```

#### data

```
m1 <- matrix(c(1, -0.25, 1, -0.25, 1, 2, 0.2, 0.3, 3), ncol=3)
```